# BarcodeDetector dont work and return false

Tags: java, android, c, android-studio

I come to you for your help on the following:

I develop an application that uses the barcode, but the problem arises when I run the activity that contains the reading of the camera : `barcode.isOperational()` return false.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.qr_scan_layout);
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
    cameraView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    barcode = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
            .build();
    if (!barcode.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Couldn't setup the detector", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();
    }
```

.......

and in the run there is the following message:

> Blockquote
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
>   W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast routecom.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: V2 version check failed
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzas
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 244 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zze;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 456: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacw.zzg
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 22 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzacw;
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4664: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4665: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4613: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method llu.b
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1187 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lllu;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4664: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4665: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13946: Lcom/google/android/chimera/ContextThemeWrapper;.createDisplayContext (Landroid/view/Display;)Landroid/content/Context;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2263 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2263 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2262 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 2264 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1777: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method qu.a
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 579 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lqu;
>   D/libc: pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x411e4645, tls=0x55379f00, arg=0x5269d860
>   D/libc: pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x411e4645
>           , tls=0x55379f00, arg=0x5269d860
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1647: Landroid/app/NotificationManager;.getNotificationChannel (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/app/NotificationChannel;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1601: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setChannelId (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1689: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1689: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 1541: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.permissionToOp (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method afw.d
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 384 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lafw;
>   I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 1054 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 1053 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 1054 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
>   I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: false
>   I/Vision: Request download for engine barcode
>   W/BarcodeNativeHandle: Native handle not yet available. Reverting to no-op handle.
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
>   W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via fast routecom.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: V2 version check failed
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702
>   I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so
>   I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: false
>   D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5537f000 size:159744 offset:0 fd:89
>   D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x40a67000 size:4096 offset:0 fd:91
>   D/memalloc: ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5537f000 size:159744
>   D/memalloc: ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x40a67000 size:4096

here is my `Build.Gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jconceptstudio.cd.mobilecheque"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

}

### when I remove the barcode.isOperational () condition, the activity works but the barcode detection does not work.

Please note :

However, I noticed the presence of the following lines in my run and I do not know why it happens.

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced  from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzas
>
> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacw.zzg
>
> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method llu.b
>
> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method qu.a
>
> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method afw.d